# Scroll multiple splits simultaneously in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, scroll

In IntelliJ IDEA I often split the tabs vertically in order to be able to see multiple files at the same time. This can be useful when the two (or more) files have the same (or similar) structure and I want to compare them (e.g. language files).

My problem is that I'd like to scroll the two splits simultaneously, but can't figure out how (if possible). Is there any setting/plugin for this?

Answer (score 40):

To compare two files in IntelliJ IDEA 14, just select them in the `Project` view (keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed for multi-selection) and choose `Compare Two File` from the context menu. This will open the **[Differences Viewer](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/differences-viewer.html)**. You can also compare a file with the clipboard or the editor contents.

The Difference Viewer scrolls both files simultaneously (there is a button to disable sync'd scrolling) and allows editing both. Differences are highlighted by word, by line, or not at all.

Comment: This is a good alternative but it wasn't exactly was I was looking for. There are some limitations to the editor in the Differences Viewer.

Comment: This won't work for e.g. two DB tables from different schemas opened side-by-side to compare contents, which is exactly what I am doing right now. IntelliJ allows me to do that without using an external SQL editor, which is great. Being able to sync-scroll these two tabs would just be the cherry on top.

Comment: I'm comparing legacy Java source (right pane) to a current version (left pane), which intellij has auto-formatted. Consequently, methods in each file start at different line numbers. The Diff Viewer handles this scenario poorly and 'large' files (>5000 LOC) exacerbates the problem. Auto-formatting the legacy source doesn't help as much as I think it should. Not sure why...

Answer (score 5):

[Joined / Wraparound / Continuous Tab Scrolling plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8028) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like what I was looking for. But I couldn't get it to work properly. I guess they will fix it in later releases (it's an alpha release now).

Comment: I was looking for something similar - as far as I can see this plugin just scrolls the same file split into two tabs (can't get it to start scrolling otherwise).  This isn't much use, and I don't really understand what use it would be!  Any idea?

Comment: It has not been updated for 6 years and is not compatible with the current versions of JB IDEs